# Regular Expression for Password Validation Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, cocoa-touch

Can anyone Please Help me i need a regular expression Password Validation.

Condition : Password should be maximum of 8 characters numeric or alphabetic with atleast one special characters

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you want to allow `>`? What did you tried?

Comment: Simple use character range length and use NSScanner for string searching which types of characters is exist or not.

Comment: Yes.Any Special Character we r Allowing.

Comment: i mean a single special character only.  `maximum of 8 characters` includes 0 also.

Comment: Max-8 Chars,Atleast one Special Char,includes 0

Comment: the user should have the possibility to use more than 8 chars.

Comment: I find regex (-only) approaches often limiting. you could break it down in several parts: 1: simple string operations to check it it has the right length, 2: regex to check if special chars are present, 3: regex or string operations to check that no whitespace is there. I wrote an article that also covers multi-step validating: http://blog.vikingosegundo.de/2014/07/16/lighter-viewcontrollers-block-based-intentions/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^(?=.{2,8}$)(?=.*?[A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*?[\W_])[\w\W]+
```

This regular expression allowes 2 to 8 character passwords. It requires to have at least 1 alphanumeric (letter/number) character and 1 non-alphanumeric character. You can test it [here](http://www.regexr.com/).

If you want to change the minimum characters required or higher the maximum. Just change the 2 or 8.

Comment: got warning : Unknown escape sequence '\W'

Comment: @DhavalBhimani i got the same warning. Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 3):

SOLUTION :

```
-(BOOL)isValidPassword:(NSString *)checkString{
NSString *stricterFilterString = @"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[$@$#!%*?&])[A-Za-z\\d$@$#!%*?&]{8,}";
NSPredicate *passwordTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", stricterFilterString];
return [passwordTest evaluateWithObject:checkString];
}
```

TEST :

```
 NSLog(@"%@", [self isValidPassword:@"D33p@k$235#@df"] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

OUTPUT :

```
YES
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**

check if the password lenght more than or equal 8 and have lowercase ,
uppercase ,decimalDigits and special characters like !@#$%^&*()_-+ is
optional.

**Why i not use regular expression ?**

Because it's difficult to support reserved characters in regular
expression syntax.

---

> ```
> func isValidated(_ password: String) -> Bool {
>     var lowerCaseLetter: Bool = false
>     var upperCaseLetter: Bool = false
>     var digit: Bool = false
>     var specialCharacter: Bool = false
>
>     if password.characters.count  >= 8 {
>         for char in password.unicodeScalars {
>             if !lowerCaseLetter {
>                 lowerCaseLetter = CharacterSet.lowercaseLetters.contains(char)
>             }
>             if !upperCaseLetter {
>                 upperCaseLetter = CharacterSet.uppercaseLetters.contains(char)
>             }
>             if !digit {
>                 digit = CharacterSet.decimalDigits.contains(char)
>             }
>             if !specialCharacter {
>                 specialCharacter = CharacterSet.punctuationCharacters.contains(char)
>             }
>         }
>         if specialCharacter || (digit && lowerCaseLetter && upperCaseLetter) {
>             //do what u want
>             return true
>         }
>         else {
>             return false
>         }
>     }
>     return false
> }
> let isVaildPass:Bool = isValidated("Test**00+-")
> print(isVaildPass)
> ```