# How to validate a password which must contain either number or alphabets(or both) as well as special characters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

hi am currently using the following to validate the password but i want to include special characters also. Currently it contains only numbers and alphabets. Please help.

```
 - (BOOL)validatePassword:(NSString *) password{
    NSString *ACCEPTABLE_CHARECTERS = @"0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ACCEPTABLE_CHARECTERS] invertedSet];
    NSString *filtered = [[password componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    return [password isEqualToString:filtered];
}
```

Comment: You can look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15132276/password-validation-in-uitextfield-in-ios) or [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423427/regular-expression-for-password-validation-objective-c)

Comment: You can look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15132276/password-validation-in-uitextfield-in-ios) or [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423427/regular-expression-for-password-validation-objective-c)

Comment: Did you try adding the special characters to `ACCEPTABLE_CHARECTERS`? BTW - you misspelled "CHARACTERS".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try this

```
- (BOOL)validatePassword:(NSString *) password{
    if(password.length == 0){
    return NO;
    }
    NSString *regex = @"^(?=(.*\d){2})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%])[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%]{8,}";
    NSPredicate *passwordPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];
    return [passwordPredicate evaluateWithObject:password];
}
```

**EXPLANATION**

`(?=(.*\d){2})` - uses lookahead `(?=)` and says the password must contain at least 2 digits

`(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` - uses lookahead and says the password must contain an alpha

`(?=.*[!@#$%])` - uses lookahead and says the password must contain 1 or more special characters which are defined

`[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%]` - dictates the allowed characters

`{8,}` - says the password must be at least 8 characters long

It might need a little tweaking e.g. specifying exactly which special characters you need but it should do the trick.

Comment: Good representation... @PiyushSharma

Comment: @Daniella D'Cruz :  if my answer is what you were looking for, you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)validatePassword:(NSString *) password{
    NSString *COMMON_CHARECTERS = @"0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    NSString *SPECIAL_CHARECTERS = @"@#$%^&*";
    NSCharacterSet *cs_common = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:COMMON_CHARECTERS];
    NSCharacterSet *cs_special = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:SPECIAL_CHARECTERS];
    NSString *filtere_common = [[password componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs_common] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    NSString *filtere_special = [[password componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs_special] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    BOOL valid = (password.length == (filtere_common.length + filtere_special.length));
    return valid;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use regex to identify use of special character. like

^([a-zA-Z+]+[0-9+]+[&@!#+]+)$

You can use character sets as well to validate password:-  [Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15132276/password-validation-in-uitextfield-in-ios?lq=1)

Comment: You mean `^[a-zA-Z0-9&@!#]+$`

Comment: @rmaddy yes ..... didn't get much time to look into it, but have already used this kind of solution.